# A expressão "por exemplo" junto com "como"

Tags: expressões, pontuação, vírgula

Gostaria de saber se utilizar a expressão "por exemplo" junto com a palavra "como" é correto. Por exemplo:

> Para programar alguns requisitos são essenciais como, por exemplo, a lógica de programação.

Vejo sentido em isolar com vírgulas "por exemplo" depois de "como", pois ela está deslocada na frase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Como* já serve para [introduzir exemplos](https://dicionario.priberam.org/como):

12. Usa-se para apresentar um ou mais exemplos (ex.: tem muitas conquistas no palmarés, como medalhas nacionais e internacionais).

Portanto *como por exemplo* pode geralmente ser substituído por simplesmente ou *como* ou *por exemplo*:

> Para programar, alguns requisitos são essenciais, como a lógica de programação.
>   Para programar, alguns requisitos são essenciais — por exemplo, a lógica de programação.

Ainda assim, *como por exemplo* é muito usado, talvez para reforçar a natureza não exaustiva da lista de que se segue. Aí, [incluir *por exemplo* entre vírgulas é facultativo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/virgulas-com-contudo-porem-e-como-por-exemplo/27656). Já a vírgula antes de *como* me parece aqui bem mais importante:

> Para programar, alguns requisitos são essenciais, como por exemplo a lógica de programação.

Por outro lado, se deslocarmos *como por exemplo* para a posição a seguir a *requisitos*, a vírgula pode não ser necessária (e temos mais uma leitura em que *como ...* está a modificar apenas *alguns requisitos*):

> Para programar, são essenciais alguns requisitos como por exemplo a lógica de programação.

Ainda assim, na frase acima, eu poria uma vírgula antes de *como*, ou poria *por exemplo* entre vírgulas.

Answer (score 1):

Não haveria razão para não combinar essas palavras, mas a sua frase está confusa. Para deixar mais fácil de interpretar:

> Para programar, são essenciais alguns requisitos como, por exemplo, a
>   lógica da programação.